# How to use the result of the previous call of a function as an implied parameter to the next call?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner of C and I just wrote a ftn that consume two number and return the gcd of them. Now I'm thinking how do you find a gcd **using pointer** if you just consume one number. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to do it? Thx.

```
Example:
gcd(5) = 5 (gcd of 5 and itself)
gcd(10) = 5 (gcd of 10 and 5(from the last call))
gcd (4) = 1 (gcd of 4 and 5(from the last call))
gcd (7) = 1 (gcd of 7 and 1(from the last call))
```

Comment: Huh? The `GCD(n,n)` is, of course `n`

Comment: Are you trying to get the GCD for a series of numbers?

Comment: It might help if you explain your reasons for wanting to do this. It seems quite odd since the mathematical definition of GCD requires two numbers.

Comment: @Code-Guru It actually takes two numbers "a" and "b". "a" is what the gcd ftn consume. "b" is the result from the last call.

Comment: @IMPERFECT Why do you want to have a GCD function that only "consumes" one number?

Comment: @Code-Guru The title of this question is my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static variable inside the function, without using any pointers.

```
int PreviousGcd( int n )
{
    static int previous = -1 ; //pick a magic number


    if( previous == -1 )
    {
        previous = n ;
        return previous ;
    }
    else
    {
        int result = gcd( n  , previous ) ;
        previous = n ;
        return result ;
    }
}
```

If you really want pointers you can pass the address of  `n` instead.

Comment: Isn't gcd only consume one number? How come int gcd = gcd( n  , internal ) ; here consume two number?

Comment: Just pass the address of `n` and dereference it in the function.

Comment: @IMPERFECT Yeah, i forgot to rename the function, gcd() inside is the function that calculates the actual gcd.

Comment: *internal = n;* also shouldn't occur until after *if(internal == -1)*. Also, maybe it'd be clearer to the OP if 'internal' was renamed 'previousResult'.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement was a pointer to an `int`. But, the pointer could be to two `int`s, so that the result of the previous computation can be stashed in the second `int`. To illustrate:

```
int input[2] = { 0, 0 };

*input = 5;
printf("%d\n", gcd(input));
*input = 10;
printf("%d\n", gcd(input));
*input = 4;
printf("%d\n", gcd(input));
*input = 7;
printf("%d\n", gcd(input));

int gcd (int *v) {
    if (v[1] == 0) v[1] = v[0];
    /* ...compute GCD of v[0] and v[1], store result in v[1] */
    return v[1];
}
```